# Write a javascript function to check whether a word or a sentence is palindrome or not irrespective of case and spaces

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem statement.
Write a javascript function to check whether a word or a sentence is a palindrome or not irrespective of case and spaces.
Here is my code for checking the palindrome number but I don't know how to check for white spaces.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPalindrome() {
      var revStr = "";
      var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
      var i = str.length;
      for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
        revStr = revStr + str.charAt(j);
      }
      if (str == revStr) {
        alert("The entry is Palindrome");
      } else {
        alert("The entry is not a Palindrome");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <form>

    Enter a String/Number: <input type="text" id="str" name="string" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="checkPalindrome();" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect the output should show the results ignoring white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some built-in methods like [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to reverse the string:

```js
function checkPalindrome() {
  var str = document.getElementById("str").value;
  var revStr = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  if(str == revStr) {
    alert("The entry is Palindrome");
  }  
  else {
    alert("The entry is not a Palindrome");
  }
}
```

```html
Enter a String/Number: <input type="text" id="str" name="string" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="checkPalindrome();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function checkPalindrome() {
  var s=document.getElementById("str").value;  

  var str = s.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
  var revStr = [...str].reverse().join``;

  if (str == revStr) {
    alert("The entry is Palindrome");
  } else {
    alert("The entry is not a Palindrome");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a String/Number: 
  <input type="text" id="str" name="string" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="checkPalindrome(this);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use **.equalsIgnoreCase()** method instead of **==** when comparing the string with the reverse string

```
var str="ma d Am";
        var revStr="";
        for(int j=str.length()-1; j>=0; j--) {
//            revStr =(str.charAt(j)==' ')?revStr+" " :revStr+(str.charAt(j));
            revStr = revStr+(str.charAt(j));
        }
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(revStr)) {
            alert("The entry is Palindrome");
        }
        else {
            alert("The entry is not a Palindrome");
        }
    }
```